# Log a user into their subdomain after registration with Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I'm using Devise for authentication in my Rails 3 app.  The application uses PostgreSQL schemas and the Apartment gem to facilitate multi-tenancy.

Logging in and out of a specific subdomain is working great *after* an account is created.  Users can only login on the subdomain for their specific account, which is great.

Here's where I'm running into issues...

A brand new user hits the sign up URL at:

`http://foo.com/signup`

By default, when they click submit, the new account is created, but the user is sent to:

`http://foo.com/dashboard`

Instead, I want them to go to:

`http://myaccount.foo.com/dashboard`

In order to achieve this, I overrode the `after_sign_up_path_for` method in my `registrations_controller.rb` file:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  root_url(:subdomain => resource.account.subdomain)
end
```

This works as intended--it loads the correct URL--but the user's session was created for the root domain (foo.com) instead of the subdomain, so the user is asked to sign in.

One suggestion I found is to change the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to:

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => :all
```

But this allows anyone to login to an account on any subdomain, which obviously isn't cool.

**Question:** How can I ensure that the session created upon **signup** is valid for the subdomain that was created during the signup process

Comment: You need to change the cookie like you wrote in your question. otherwise the user will always be unknown on the subdomain. A simple solution would be to write a before-filter or extend your existing login-logic to check for the right subdomain. This is something, that is usually done, because you don't want to rely on cookies for authentication.

Comment: @phoet Hmm, I thought about that.  So should I do `:domain => '.mydomain'` (to allow cross subdomain cookies) and then modify my `before_filter` to check the right subdomain?

Comment: i used a middleware for the cookie stuff: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/app/middlewares/cookie_domain.rb

Comment: @phoet I'm not sure your middleware example will work for me because the cookie while the user is still on the root domain.  Or does it re-cookie the user once they hit a subdomain?  The thing I'm having the most trouble with is making Devise do an additional check on subdomain. Any advice there?  I think if I can achieve this, I'll just enabled cross-subdomain cookies and rely on my auth code for security.

Comment: `before_filter` is good choice or just add a warden strategy for subdomain check which check for subdomain for valid check for user you can also use warden hook like `set_user` or `after_autentication` to achieve the same

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `domain: :all` option in your config.session_store and just have a before_action just as suggested by some in the comments.

So you'll still have the code in config/initializers/session_store.rb or in config/application.rb:

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => :all
```

Then in your application_controller add the following code:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :check_subdomain

def check_subdomain
  unless request.subdomain == current_user.account.subdomain
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are not authorized to access that subdomain."
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, but one minor wrinkle: if I move sessions to the database (as `session_store.rb` suggests), when I create a brand new account (at http://example.com) I'm redirected to http://foo.example.com and I'm logged in (great!).  However, the very next action I take forces me to login again. If I keep session in a cookie, the session persists as desired. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? In Rails 4, activerecord-session_store has been removed. The only options available are :cookie_store, :mem_cache_store and :disabled. If your session data exceeds 4kb, then you'll want to use :mem_cache_store. Otherwise, it's best to stick with :cookie_store. It's not advisable to use your sql db for sessions since it is slower and is an unnecessary load on it. Here's an article on it: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: @RobSobers, let me know if answer has helped or if there's any clarification you need.

Comment: I'm all set.  Thanks!  I ended up going with a slightly different solution for reasons I'll add to the question, but apart from that, what you've provided will work just fine.

Comment: @Gjaldon, I am trying to do the same thing without using the devise Can you please guide me what to do ??

Comment: @Gjaldon I did exactly as u said but it is giving me error `undefined method `subdomain' for nil:NilClass` before_action works for every action can u help me with that please. after registration I want to bypass sign_in and url should be live pqrst.example.com/dashboard

Answer (score 2):

Override the devise session controller.

Create a file with the **exact path** `app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`

Override the sessions_controller class in that controller. Paste in the code found at the link. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
 # copy-paste the devise session controller below.
 ...
end
```

Edit the `create` action to suit your needs.

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

I'm looking to see if I can figure out how exactly to make this work, but I know for sure that the result you want is attainable by overriding the devise session controller.

**EDIT**

If you are using cross-subdomain cookies, you could enforce the subdomain session with a before_filter. For example

```
before_action do 
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'That subdomain does not belong to you' if request.subdomain != current_user.subdomain
end
```

Comment: where to write this before_action as writing it in application controller will call it everytime when anymethod is called and will give error