# Devise: Login user and redirect to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I am using **Apartment** and **Devise** gem for Muti-tenancy and authentication.

I have a `sign_up` page in root domain URL(`example.com`) where I get the subdomain details from user.

I need to `sign_in` the user after successfully saving the record and redirect to the new subdomain(`sub.example.com`).

**Apartment Schemas:**

> Account => Common for all schemas(Public)
>
> User => Created seperately for each schemas(Private)

**RegistrationController**:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  
  ...
  ...

  def create
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @account = Account.new(account_params)
      if @account.valid?
        # Create & switch to the new tenant
        Apartment::Tenant.create(@account.subdomain)
        Apartment::Tenant.switch!(@account.subdomain)
        @account.save

        sign_in(:user, @account.user)
        redirect_to root_url(subdomain: "#{Apartment::Tenant.current}")
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  ...
  ...

  protected
  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name, :subdomain, user_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end
end
```

The above code successfully redirects to the new subdomain but, It is not signing_in the user although I am signing_in the user before redirect.

Anyone please help me to redirect the user as `signed_in` to the new subdomain.

Thank you..

Comment: Does redirecting to `root_url` preserves the session cookies?

Comment: @31piy, I tried removing the authentication in root_url and tried printing the session `p session['warden.user.user.key']` in controller action but it returns `nil`

Comment: Please check if the session IDs are same before and after the redirection.

Comment: @31piy The session id in the `create` action after calling `redirect_to` is `f3911a8b73e04ad0afbcb126412b5135` and the session id in the `root_path` action after redirection is `2e34cbab7f479107c7efb14b05425504`

Comment: Yup, exactly! If sessions aren't same, then the signed in user won't be shared across the domains. You need to find a way so that the sessions can be shared between the domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved this issue by adding `:domain => :all` or the rootdomain `:domain => 'example.com'` option in `session_store` which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20597188/4172728) answer.

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => :all
```

(or)

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => 'example.com'
```